# Adding pagination to custom Wordpress function

Tags: functions, pagination

I am trying to add pagination to posts however i cannot figure out how to get it to work - it simply does not show the pagination as i need it to. It should display the first 15 posts on the first page, then should paginate all other posts.

Any ideas?

```
function latestreleases()   {

$args = array( 'cat' => '-1, -2', 'paged' => $paged, 'posts_per_page' => 15 );                  
$last_5_posts_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while($last_5_posts_query->have_posts()) : 
    $last_5_posts_query->the_post();
    $link = get_permalink();
    $title = get_the_title();
    $description = excerpt(16);
    $details = 'Watch ';
    $readmore = 'Read more...';
    $paginate = paginate_links();                

    $content .= '<div class="all-latest-movies">';
    $content .= '<h3><a href='.$link.' target="_blank">'.$title.'</a></h3>';
    $content .= '<div class="thumbnail"><a href=" '.$link. ' " target="_blank">'
    . get_the_post_thumbnail( null, "home-movie-thumbnail") 
    . '</a></div>';
    $content .= '<div class="ratings">'. ( function_exists("the_ratings") ? the_ratings() : '' ) .'</div>';
    $content .= '<div class="description">' .$description. '&nbsp;<a href= '.$link.' >' .$readmore. '</div>';
    $content .= '<div class="view-listing"><a href= '.$link.' target="_blank" >' .$details. $title. '</a></div>';
    $content .= '</div><!-- .fetured-movies -->';
endwhile;

return $content;

echo '<nav>';
echo  '<div>'.get_next_posts_link('Older', $the_query->max_num_pages).'</div>'; //Older Link using max_num_pages
echo  '<div>'.get_previous_posts_link('Newer', $the_query->max_num_pages).'</div>'; //Newer Link using max_num_pages
echo "</nav>";
}

add_shortcode('LatestReleases', 'latestreleases' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    $last_5_posts_query = new WP_Query( $args . $paged );
```

i didn't test it but it may work.

Comment: I tried that, no luck :(